# unable to run anything parallel using ((AndroidDriver) driver).runAppInBackground(Duration.ofSeconds(80));

Tags: automation, appium-android

I am testing two Apps A and B .
I need to go A keep it open and switch to APP B do some button clicks(while A is still running on background) and come back again to app A.

By the time I switch to app B using

`// finish some tasks on B`
// driver.startActivity(new Activity("com.example.APP_A", ".MainActivity"));
The app A is dead. Whatever I expected to happen didn't happen because its already got killed(I don't know why)

So I tried `((AndroidDriver) driver).runAppInBackground(Duration.ofSeconds(80));`
The above line before I make switch to app B . This works when I stop there and perform manual action in B an come back to A again.

But in automation since the above runAppInBackground method is synchronous ..I can't execute any actions I wanted to do in app B while A is running in background.

Either I wanted that runAppInBackground to be asynchronous method or
some way I need to keep my APP A alive during switching to app B ?
Any suggestions please ?